Terraform nested for loop producing unexpected result
Given this module input:
variable "port_mapping_metadata" {
  type = map(object({
    target_type                       = optional(string, "instance")
    ssl_policy                        = optional(string)
    listener_cert_arn                 = optional(string)
    additional_SNI_listener_cert_arns = optional(list(string),[])
    ...

I'm trying to create a resource per port_mapping_metadata (if not null, keys may be duplicates across resources), per item in additional_SNI_listener_cert_arns (if not empty). So for the following input:
  "bar" = {
    vpc_name            = "foo"
    name                = "bar"
    type                = "application"
    port_mapping_metadata = {
      "forward" = {
        instance_names                    = ["inst"]
        listener_cert_arn                 = "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:1234:certificate/abcd"
        additional_SNI_listener_cert_arns = ["arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:1234:certificate/defg", "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:1234:certificate/hijk"]
  "bax" = {
    vpc_name            = "foo"
    name                = "bax"
    type                = "application"
    port_mapping_metadata = {
      "forward" = {
        instance_names                    = ["inst2"]
        listener_cert_arn                 = "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:1234:certificate/abcd"
        additional_SNI_listener_cert_arns = ["arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:1234:certificate/zle"]
(under another key)
  "bar" = {
    vpc_name            = "foo"
    name                = "bar"
    type                = "application"
    port_mapping_metadata = {
      "forward" = {
        instance_names                    = ["inst"]
        listener_cert_arn                 = "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:1234:certificate/abcd"

I would expect the following for_each result:
{
  "bar-0" = "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:1234:certificate/defg"
  "bar-1" = "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:1234:certificate/hijk"
  "bax-0" = "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:1234:certificate/zle"
}

I have tried writing the resource as with a for_each as follows:
resource "aws_lb_listener_certificate" "additional_SNI_listener_certs" {
  for_each = {
    for k, v in var.port_mapping_metadata : k => {
      for index, cert_arn in try(v.additional_SNI_listener_cert_arns, []) : "${k}-${index}" => cert_arn
    }
    if try(v.additional_SNI_listener_cert_arns, []) != [] && try(v.additional_SNI_listener_cert_arns, null) != null
  }
  ##this _should_ be "{ "listener_name-0" = "arn1" , ... }"

  listener_arn   = aws_lb_listener.all[element(split("-", each.key), 0)].arn ##this should be "listener_name"
  certificate_arn = each.value ##this should be "arn1"
}

But for some reason I get the error:
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│ 
│   on .terraform/modules/load_balancer/load_balancer.tf line 235, in resource "aws_lb_listener_certificate" "additional_SNI_listener_certs":
│  235:   certificate_arn = each.value
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is object with no attributes
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "certificate_arn": string required.

I can't understand why each.value in the resource is not a single string arn1. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I can't figure out what it is. Also open to any other way of doing this.

The error message cites each.value["cert_arn"] but that is absent from the config in the question.

I had pasted on older error, I was trying to figure out what the keys were. I have corrected the error.

I am having issues with TF parsing your config without erroring on invalid syntax. Assuming your config is syntacically valid you can debug this by isolating your input variable, and then using an output to display the transformed structure you are constructing in the for_each meta-param. That would greatly assist your debugging. The console command could also similarly assist with less complex transformations and inputs.

By looking at your code, I think the for_each is getting the following map as input. However, you must verify it by adding a terraform output to print the result of the expression.
{
  bar = {
    "bar-0" = "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:1234:certificate/defg"
    "bar-1" = "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:1234:certificate/hijk"
  }
  bax = {
    "bax-0" = "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:1234:certificate/zle"
  }
}

Now as per your requirement, to get the following map input to the for_each
{
  "bar-0" = "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:1234:certificate/defg"
  "bar-1" = "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:1234:certificate/hijk"
  "bax-0" = "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:1234:certificate/zle"
}

You need to modify the code to the following
locals {

  original_for_each_expr = {
    for k, v in var.port_mapping_metadata : k => {
      for index, cert_arn in try(v.additional_SNI_listener_cert_arns, []) : "${k}-${index}" => cert_arn
    }
    if try(v.additional_SNI_listener_cert_arns, []) != [] && try(v.additional_SNI_listener_cert_arns, null) != null
  }

  desired_for_each_expr = zipmap(
    flatten(
      [ for i in local.original_for_each_expr : keys(i) ]
    ),
    flatten(
      [ for i in local.original_for_each_expr : values(i) ]
    )
  ) 

}

resource "aws_lb_listener_certificate" "additional_SNI_listener_certs" {
  for_each = local.desired_for_each_expr
  ...
}

Also, as I suggested earlier, add terraform outputs to see if you are getting the desired value from the expression to pass it to the for_each.
output "original_for_each_expr" {
  value = local.original_for_each_expr
}

output "desired_for_each_expr" {
  value = local.desired_for_each_expr
}


Indeed, the original expression result is as you noted. Thanks for the tip on adding outputs, I always forget about that
